# Repeat beamer presentation automatically

Tags: beamer, automation

I have a `beamer` presentation which should run automatically on its own during an exhibition. I already added `\transduration{5}\transblindshorizontal` to show the next slide automatically after 5 seconds, but I still need to figure out how to jump back to the very first slide after the very last slide has been shown. I can't find anything in the `beamer` manual.

PS: I'm not looking for anything like `\againframe`. The whole presentation should repeat itself over and over again for almost a whole day.

Comment: Looking at the source, `\transduration` is a wrapper around the `hyperref` key `pdfpageduration` (which does not seem to be documented). I suspect what you need here is a PDF special.

Comment: @Joseph: Indeed: http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2007-09/msg01102.html

Comment: I took a look at the PDF Reference. I don't see an in-file instruction for looping a PDF, only the one for page duration. So you probably need to set this in the viewer, as suggested.

Comment: I did something like that in the past, and the solution was quite ugly and dirty: I coded a bash script with my PDF viewer `evince` opening (in the background, `&`) a `n`th page with `--page-index=<n>`, `sleep <m>` seconds then going to next page, *ad nauseam*. I'm very curious on a possible TeX solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As one option, outside of LaTeX, you could set up Adobe Reader to do this. Under `Preferences` -> `Full Screen`, select the *Loop after last page* option:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That would already do it in my case. However, having this setting as part of the PDF would be even better. Because of your answer I searched now for "loop after last page latex" and found a PDF special which does it: http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2007-09/msg01102.html

Answer (score 14):

Because of Werner's answer I now found the `comp.text.tex` post 
https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.text.tex/kYnAVKbuq50/vZZFuBK1mlMJ
which provides the following code. It uses PDF low-level commands to loop after the last page. This is basically the same as the viewer setting in Werner's answer, but part of the PDF. It works for me under Ubuntu Linux 11.04 with Adobe Reader 9.4.2. No idea if this is viewer dependent. At the very least the viewer must support some basic javascript.

Put the following in the preamble of the `beamer` document:

```
\hypersetup{pdfstartpage=1}
\pdfcatalog{
/AA <<
/WC <<
/S/JavaScript/JS (app.fs.loop=false;)
>>
>>
}
\pdfpageattr{
/AA <<
/O <<
/S/JavaScript/JS (app.fs.loop=true;)
>>
>>
}
```

An alterntive solution I figured by browsing other `beamer` questions is to use 
`impressive` to show the PDF file. Using the `-w` option the PDF is repeated and the transient time can be set using `-a 5`. However, this tool converts the PDF to an image which adds some small but ugly white frame at the lower and right site. Also I really prefer to stay with only PDF to keep things simple.

Comment: Is it possible to modify this to create a loop only of a few slides of a presentation? I've tried playing around with those `pdfstartpage` and `.loop` parameters over there but it didn't work.